# Problem with style with svg file for linear layer

Tags: layers, vector, style, sld

I have a problem with styling line with svg file. Line should be style with image like below: [image]

but on layer it looks like this: [image]

My style is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:UserStyle xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <sld:Name>AtlasStyler 2.0-SNAPSHOT</sld:Name>
  <sld:Title/>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <sld:Name>UNIQUE_VALUE_LINE</sld:Name>
    <sld:Title>UniqueValuesLineRuleList</sld:Title>
    <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Title>NLZ</sld:Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:Literal>ALL_LABEL_CLASSES_ENABLED</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>ALL_LABEL_CLASSES_ENABLED</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:Not>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>przeznacz</ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>przeznacz</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
            </ogc:Not>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>przeznacz</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>NLZ</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:And>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1.0E20</sld:MaxScaleDenominator> 
      <sld:LineSymbolizer> 
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#2121dd</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 </sld:CssParameter> 
        </sld:Stroke>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
<sld:LineSymbolizer>
 <sld:Stroke>
 <sld:GraphicStroke>
        <sld:Graphic>
           <sld:ExternalGraphic>
            <sld:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple"  xlink:href="http://192.168.0.215/bundles/img/mpzp/lzn.svg"/>
            <sld:Format>image/svg+xml</sld:Format>
          </sld:ExternalGraphic>
          <sld:Size>
            <ogc:Literal>12.0</ogc:Literal>
          </sld:Size>
        </sld:Graphic>
 </sld:GraphicStroke>
 </sld:Stroke> 
 </sld:LineSymbolizer>    
    </sld:Rule>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Title>OLZ</sld:Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:Literal>ALL_LABEL_CLASSES_ENABLED</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>ALL_LABEL_CLASSES_ENABLED</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:Not>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>przeznacz</ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>przeznacz</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
            </ogc:Not>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>przeznacz</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>OLZ</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:And>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1.0E20</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <sld:LineSymbolizer> 
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 </sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
  </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
```

Someone know what is wrong and what to do to have line like first imga?